# Ayuda con Frappe grantt

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, data

hola estoy haciendo un gantt con js, estoy usando frappe gantt, pero al momento de realizar la funcion para generarlo me aparece este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
el texto que se ve arriva es console.log(tasks). Aqui una muestra de mi js:

```css
/*Llamar generacion de grantt*/
function generar_diagrama(data){
var tasks=data;
console.log(tasks)
setTimeout(function(){
var gantt = new Gantt('#gantt', tasks, {
    on_view_change: function() {
        var bars = document.querySelectorAll(" .bar-group");
        for (var i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
            bars[i].addEventListener("mousedown", stopEvent, true);
        }
        var handles = document.querySelectorAll(" .handle-group");
        for (var i = 0; i < handles.length; i++) {
            handles[i].remove();
        }
    }
});    
},500)

}
//DIAGRAMA DE GRANTT


/*Consulta de datos*/
var json;
    $.ajax({
    url: "diagrama",
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"html",
    data:{},
    success:function(data){

    generar_diagrama(data);
    }
});
```

Y mi consulta de controller y model:

```
Controller:
    public function diagrama()
    {
      $id=$this->input->post("id");
     $data=$this->Home_model->diagrama($id);
      echo json_encode($data);
    }

    Model:
            public function diagrama($id)
        {
            $query= $this->db
            ->select('t.id as id,t.fecha_inicio as start ,t.titulo as name,t.fecha_fin as end,t.porcentaje as progress')
            ->from("tareas as t")
            ->join('usuario', 't.usuario1 = usuario.id')
            ->get();
            return $query->result();
        }
```

y el objeto del index:

```
<svg id="gantt"></svg>
```

Lo extraño es que si en ves de poner como valor 'data' a 'tasks', pongo el texto que el 'console.log' me imprime si funciona...

Comment: Que tienes en el `home.js` en la linea 83 ?

Comment: var gantt = new Gantt('#gantt', tasks, {... es la generacion de  la grafica . #gantt es el id del campo donde se genera y tasks es la variable con los datos